# Can we have a link to question when editing from review?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits

When editing ***from review***, like when improving an edit, there is actually no way to get back to the question. Sometimes I feel the need when improving an edit to check back on the suggested edit, or look at the comments (for ex. if the OP pasted code in comment I like to include it in the edit).

Usually what I do is to search the question by copy pasting the title in a new tab, though if I already changed the title I might not be able to do this. If I'm editing an answer this is not possible either.

Could it be possible to add a link to the question in the edit screen? Or is there any easy way to get back to the question that I missed?

Comment: Cancelling your edit takes you back to the main review screen.  From there the title itself is a link.  But this requires discarding any effort you've already put into editing the post...

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's a possibility - I can of course copy my edit before cancelling, though if I edited the title as well I need to temporarily store it in an open notepad. There is workarounds but it would be such much easier to just have a link to click on.

Comment: Small workaround: right click browser tab - duplicate, cancel in duplicate screen.

Comment: @J.Constantine I didn't thought of that and this is even easier than that: when you duplicate the tab you're back to the review screen and don't have to click on cancel.

Comment: @vard - Unrelated to question but I highly recommend ClipX, a clipboard manager. Lets you store multiple items in your clipboard and switch between them with shortcut keys.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I will give it a look, thanks.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: Seconded. I've never used that particular program (I currently use Clipman on Xubuntu Linux), but any decent clipboard manager with multiple slots is definitely a huge productivity boost over the basic one-slot clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

Updated for review queues: if you right click on the edit link and choose *Open in a new tab* you can force your browser to open the edit link in a new tab preserving the original question in the previous tab.  This action is required because simply holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking the link will open the link in the same tab.

Comment: That's incorrect. When you do that you're back to the previous review, not the review you're actually editing.

Comment: @vard: ... although Ctrl-/Cmd-/middle-clicking the *current* history entry will do the job.